# Can simple finder be configured on macOS Catalina 10.15.1?

Tags: macos, finder, catalina

I am unable to activate simple finder in macOS Catalina 10.15.1 (actually this is noticed to be missing since the beta 19A558d).

I have tried `defaults write com.apple.finder InterfaceLevel -string "simple"`, which used to work before Catalina.

Are there any other settings to do this or is the feature removed?

Comment: Now that Catalina has shipped - we should be able to tell if this is gone or missing or needs GUI to enable.